# Conexão via socket entre servidores

Tags: node.js, websocket

Tenho estudado a comunicação entre dois (ou mais) servidores levantados em NodeJS via `REST` más a medida que busquei conteúdo (referencias, explanações, benchmarks, etc..) encontrei indicações de `REST` traria mais custo ao processo e `WebSocket` seria mais recomendado porém, todo material que encontrei foi referente a **cliente** (front-end) para **servidor**(back-end).

A pergunta muito sucinta é: **como conectar e trocar mensagens entre dois servidores** via "sockets" (apenas back-end)?

A implementação inicial onde usei `REST` trabalhei com **express** para mapear rotas e **superagent** para fazer requisições.

Agora ao tentar usar `WebSocket` estou usando o módulo [uws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uws)

**example.js**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('uws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 3000 });

function onMessage(message) {
    console.log('received: ' + message);
}

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', onMessage);
    ws.send('something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> A pergunta muito sucinta é: como conectar e trocar mensagens entre dois servidores via "sockets" (apenas back-end)?

Da mesma forma que você se comunica através do front-end, apenas abra a conexão com o socket server e troque mensagens.

O modelo pode variar:

```
 -------  ---->  -------------
|backend|       |socket server|
 -------  <----  -------------

 -------  ---->  -------------  ---->  -------
|backend|       |socket server|       |backend|
 -------  <----  -------------  <----  -------
```

Sinceramente eu duvido bastante que "REST traria mais custo ao processo", você vai ter mais trabalho pra gerenciar um sistema todo baseado em sockets do que um simples http rest.